# powershell: remove text from end of string

Tags: powershell

--deleted earlier text - I asked the wrong question!

ahem....

What I have is `$var = "\\unknowntext1\alwaysSame\unknowntext2"`

I need to keep only `"\\unknowntext1"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try regular expressions:

```
$foo = 'something_of_unknown' -replace 'something.*','something'
```

Or if you know only partially the 'something', then e.g.

```
'something_of_unknown' -replace '(some[^_]*).*','$1'
'some_of_unknown' -replace '(some[^_]*).*','$1'
'somewhatever_of_unknown' -replace '(some[^_]*).*','$1'
```

The `$1` is reference to group in parenthesis (the `(some[^_]*)` part).

**Edit** (after changed question):

If you use regex, then special characters need to be escaped:

```
"\\unknowntext1\alwaysSame\unknowntext2" -replace '\\\\unknowntext1.*', '\\unknowntext1'
```

or (another regex magic) use lookbehind like this:

```
"\\unknowntext1\alwaysSame\unknowntext2" -replace '(?<=\\\\unknowntext1).*', ''
```

(which is: take anything (`.*`), but there must be `\\unknowntext1` before it (`'(?<=\\\\unknowntext1)`) and replace it with empty string.

**Edit** (last)

If you know that there is something known in the middle (the `alwaysSame`), this might help:

```
"\\unknowntext1\alwaysSame\unknowntext2" -replace '(.*?)\\alwaysSame.*', '$1'
```

Comment: Edited the answer, but as I see now, I have to edit it once again ;)

Answer (score 6):

> What I have is $var = "\unknowntext1\alwaysSame\unknowntext2"
>
> I need to keep only "\unknowntext1"

Not sure this requires a regular expression. Assuming `alwaysSame` is literally always the same, as the discussion around stej's answer suggests, it seems by far the most straightforward way to accomplish this would be:

`$var.substring(0, $var.indexOf("\alwaysSame"));`

Comment: How does that not answer the question?  If you have `$var = "\\unknowntext1\alwaysSame\unknowntext2"` and you run `$var.substring(0, $var.indexOf("\alwaysSame"));`, you get `\\unknowntext1`, *QED*. Was just surprised the other answers were nontrivially more convoluted.

Comment: I notice neither of you (Hashem & Lucas) have a `powershell` tag in your profile. Lines of Powershell code always* emit their results to the "pipeline", if that's throwing you. That statement in my answer will "return" the value the OP requested; every PowerShell line of code is sort of like an implicit function which can be chained to another subsequent command. I can see how that might have confused you. I've also edited the answer to make my intent clearer to non-PS users.

Answer (score 5):

```
function Remove-TextAfter {   
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $string, 
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $value,
        [Switch]$Insensitive
    )

    $comparison = [System.StringComparison]"Ordinal"
    if($Insensitive) {
        $comparison = [System.StringComparison]"OrdinalIgnoreCase"
    }

    $position = $string.IndexOf($value, $comparison)

    if($position -ge 0) {
        $string.Substring(0, $position + $value.Length)
    }
}

Remove-TextAfter "something_of_unknown" "SoMeThInG" -Insensitive
```

Comment: Thanks for the `System.StringComparison` format.  ;^)